# Mage registry key "controller" already exists

Tags: php, magento-1.4

I have configured an ecommerce site using Magento, but it is throwing an error.

> Mage registry key "controller" already exists

I am not sure what to do.  The URL for site is http://musicademy.sweetersinging.com/store/admin

Comment: Do your Magento error logs give any further details?

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens if you try and run `Mage::run()` twice - or specifically, once more after the `index.php` bootstrap.

Sounds like a (extremely) badly written 3rd party extension or template. It (sadly) wouldn't be the first time I've seen someone execute this within a `.phtml` file.

Go through the standard debug process, refresh between each.

1. Move `app/code/local` to `app/code/local.bak`
2. Move `app/code/community` to `app/code/community.bak`
3. Move `app/design/frontend/your_custom_package` to `app/design/frontend/your_custom_package.bak`

Once you've found the cause above, then you can start to filter through the filters/dirs to check.

Comment: For me it was a bit trickier :D I left a watch expression in the debug window Mage::app()-> ...

Answer (score 0):

If you have **Magefirewall extension** installed try disabling at the webserver(by going to magento_root_dir/app/etc/modules/magefirewall.xml) and clear the cache (by deleting all the files/folders in magento_root_dir/var/cache/) if you don't have access to the admin panel. Doing this solved the issue for me on Magento CE 1.9.2.2.